# How to show month on x axis for only 12 data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am able to create a plot with the name of the month when I have 365 data points with the following code:

```
y = np.random.normal(size=365)
x = np.array(range(len(y)))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Month')
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

Here is the result, which is exactly what I'm looking for:
[image]

I would like to do the same thing but with only 12 data points (one for each month). If I just change the 365 to 12 (`y = np.random.normal(size=12)`), it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get it to show all the months in the x axis as in the first graph?

I tried passing arguments to [MonthLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator) `(bymonth, bymonthday, interval)` but none of them seemed to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You only have 12 points, so `MonthLocator` won't work as desired.
- It will be easier to set the x-axis as the month names with a list:

  - `import calendar` to get a list of month names, or type them manually, and then use `x = calendar.month_abbr[1:]`

```py
import calendar  # part of the standard library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(365)
y = np.random.normal(size=12)
x = calendar.month_abbr[1:]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Month')
```

[image]